# Dynamic Dropdown opens new fields

Tags: jquery, dropdown

In the following code shows dynamic field "Childs". User should choose the amount of children.

Choosing 1 child should open a new field for putting in the age of the child. Choosing 2 children should open 2 fields and so on.

Instead, my code opens 2 fields for 1 child and 3 for 2 children etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/milak/fhhbzgvL/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_NOA').change(function(){
        var total = $(this).val();
        $('.app_rate').each(function(index){
            if (index != 0) $(this).remove();
        });
        for (var i = 0; i <= total; i++)
        {
            $('.app_rate:first').append("Age" + i + "&nbsp;<select name=age_child" + i + "><option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option><option value=3>3</option><option value=4>4</option><option value=5>5</option><option value=6>6</option><option value=7>7</option></select>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your for-loop is running until <= total. This is one time too much (check for-loop syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Start your iterator at 1, like this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++)
```

That way your numbering will be correct too.

Answer (score 0):

Change `i <= total` to `i < total` in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want I think. It remembers the user's choises.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_NOA').change(function(){      
        var total = $(this).val();
        var ages = [];
        $('.app_rate select').each(function(index){             
            ages.push($(this).val())      
        });
        $(".app_rate").html("");
        for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++)
        {
            $('.app_rate:first').append("Age" + i + "&nbsp;<select class=select" + i + " name=age_child" + i + "><option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option><option value=3>3</option><option value=4>4</option><option value=5>5</option><option value=6>6</option><option value=7>7</option></select>");
            $(".select"+i).val(ages[i-1]);                
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="id_NOA">Childs</label>
    <select name="NOA" id="id_NOA">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="app_rate"></div>
```

Comment: great, thank you. one more question. now the name of the new fields start with ages0, ages1... how to start it from <select name="ages1">

Comment: I did start the index with one, like this.. for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++). I also updated the answer.